# Changing the size of display equation locally

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I want to increase the size of a display equation and only the equation.

The code in question is the following:

```
\begin{equation}
    \int_{0}^{n}x^2
    \label{eq:int}
\end{equation}
```

I have tried `\begingroup`

```
Normal equation
\begin{equation}
    \int_{0}^{n}x^2
    \label{eq:int1}
\end{equation}

Large equation
\begingroup
\Large
\begin{equation}
    \int_{0}^{n}x^2
    \label{eq:int2}
\end{equation}
\endgroup
```

but that also increases the size of the numbering. [image]

And `\scalebox` doesn't properly work with things like `\int`:

```
\begin{equation}
    \scalebox{1.5}{
    $\int_{0}^{n}x^2$}
    \label{eq:int}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

So I'm looking for a way to get the size of the `\Large` display equation but a normal numbering. Also, I would need a way to reference the equations (with`\ref`) and I only want sizes to change on a case by case basis, so `\DeclareMathSizes` wouldn't really work.

Comment: Use `\scalebox{<num>}{$\displaystyle ...$}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `relsize` package, which has a `\mathlarger{}` command. You should see its manual for details; the manual also cautions against using it too broadly. (Below I used it twice, which means it should be the same size as what you get from `\Large`.)

Note also that the `\scalebox` solution should work also. If I am parsing you correctly you are just missing `\displaystyle`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
Normal equation
\begin{equation}
    \int_{0}^{n}x^2
    \label{eq:int1}
\end{equation}

Large equation
\begin{equation}
    \mathlarger{\mathlarger{\int_0^n x^2}}
\end{equation}

\Large
\[ \int_0^n x^2 \]

\normalsize
\begin{equation}
    \scalebox{1.4}{$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{n}x^2$}
    \label{eq:int}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]